# Is there a way to invert an ActiveRecord::Relation query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Let's say we have the following:

```
irb> Post.where(:hidden => true).to_sql
=> "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE posts.hidden = 1"
```

**Could we somehow get an inverted SQL query out of it?**

What I am looking for, should probably look like this:

```
irb> Post.where(:hidden => true).invert.to_sql
=> "SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE NOT (posts.hidden = 1)"
```

Comment: Hmm. Bad upvote on the comment `where(:hidden => false)` by someone. That code will *not* generate the type of SQL the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 18):

With a different syntax, yes. Example:

```
posts = Post.scoped.table # or Arel::Table.new("posts")
posts.where(posts[:hidden].eq(true).not).to_sql
# => SELECT  FROM `posts` WHERE NOT ((`posts`.`hidden` = 1))
```

Comment: Not precisely what I was looking for but still a very good answer.

Comment: Did you find another way to do this? Perhaps a better syntax? Did the answer work for you?

Comment: Actually I think it's not even possible since what I am actually asking is to invert and ActiveRecord::Relation object which might or might not have multiple joins and includes which would complicate the matter too much (which WHEREs should we invert and which not?). I think I'll leave this open until an answer comes along.

Answer (score 7):

In rails 4 there is `not` suffix for this purpose:

```
Post.where.not(hidden: true).to_sql
# => SELECT FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`hidden` != 1
```

In rails 3 you can use [squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel). It gives many usefull features. And with it you can write:

```
Post.where{ hidden != true }.to_sql
# => SELECT FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`hidden` != 1
```

Answer (score 5):

We can take [Zabba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302510/is-there-a-way-to-invert-an-arel-query/5303452#5303452) further by passing the inverted query back into ActiveRecord:

```
table = Post.arel_table
query = table[:hidden].eq(true).not # the inverted query, still ARel
Post.where(query) # plug it back into ActiveRecord
```

This will return ActiveRecord objects, as you would normally expect.

Answer (score 5):

### invert_where (Rails 7+)

Starting from Rails 7, there is a new [invert_where](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-invert_where) method.

According to the docs, it:

> Allows you to invert an entire where clause instead of manually applying conditions.

```rb
class User
  scope :active, -> { where(accepted: true, locked: false) }
end

User.where(accepted: true)
# WHERE `accepted` = 1

User.where(accepted: true).invert_where
# WHERE `accepted` != 1

User.active
# WHERE `accepted` = 1 AND `locked` = 0

User.active.invert_where
# WHERE NOT (`accepted` = 1 AND `locked` = 0)
```

> Be careful because this inverts all conditions before invert_where call.

```rb
class User
  scope :active, -> { where(accepted: true, locked: false) }
  scope :inactive, -> { active.invert_where } # Do not attempt it
end

# It also inverts `where(role: 'admin')` unexpectedly.
User.where(role: 'admin').inactive
# WHERE NOT (`role` = 'admin' AND `accepted` = 1 AND `locked` = 0)
```

**Sources:**

- [invert_where](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-invert_where) from official Rails API docs.
- [Link to the PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40249).
- [BigBinary blog article about invert_where method](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-adds-invert_where).

Comment: He, I just googled a solution for a inverse where and you answered this solution yesterday. Another reason to move to rails 7  :)

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I'm looking for records with a "not true" condition (eg, false or nil) is:

```
Post.where(["(hidden IS NULL) OR (hidden = ?)", false])
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally we have the method `invert_where` with Rails 7.

```
irb> Post.where(:hidden => true).invert_where.to_sql
"SELECT \"posts\".* FROM \"posts\" WHERE \"posts\".\"hidden\" != 1"
```

Please check this [commit reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/812e90482d4c6f3b76bc99d7c9797d9106125cd5) for more details.