# Does not equal conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a where clause with an equal and does not equal condition:

```
@user = User.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :author_id != current_user.id).nil? ? (render :something) : (render :somethingelse)
```

The above does not work:

> syntax error, unexpected ')',
>   expecting tASSOC ...d, :user_id !=
>   current_user.id).nil? ? (render
>   :index) : (re...

If I change the second condition from `!=` to `=>` it will work, however.

How do I have both conditions in one where clase? Thank you

Comment: @taro I completed "Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example" this week but it didn't cover those kind of conditionals, so I'm still learning. It also suggested I start with Rails before moving on to Ruby. But thank you for your feedback.

Comment: you should use `empty?` instead of `nil?` because `where` returns an Array, per se.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's how you would use Arel to generate the query "`select * from users where user_id = ? and author_id != ?`":

```
users = User.arel_table
User.where(users[:user_id].      eq(current_user.id).and(
           users[:author_id].not_eq(current_user.id)))
```

Using Arel isn't as concise as using Hash conditions for simple conditions, but it's a lot more powerful!

Here's a link to the [full list of predications](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/Arel/Predications) (`eq`, `not_eq`, `gt`, `lt`, etc.) available with Arel.

Comment: This answer is better because it is more database agnostic. For instance, some databases do not understand `!=` but others will.

Answer (score 21):

I believe, it should be:

```
@user = User.where(['user_id = ? AND author_id <> ?', current_user.id, current_user.id])
render(@user ? :something : :somethingelse)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked too. Guess I can't get it all on one line using .nil? as I had hoped though :)

Answer (score 18):

Rails 4 has this all figured out

```
Model.where.not(:colname => nil)
#=> returns all records whose :colname values are not nil
```

Answer (score 7):

The syntax error is due to you attempting to use `!=` instead of `=>`. The `where` method does not support inequality with hashed arguments, so your not equal will need to be written using array arguments.

```
User.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(['users.author_id <> ?', current_user.id])
```

Comment: Thank you Douglas. Is there a way to use :author_id instead of having it as a literal within quotes? (not that it matters, just curious)

Comment: The only suggestion I could add to this would be to look at meta_where, which actually supports syntax very similar to what you posted in your question. https://github.com/ernie/meta_where

Comment: You can also use :author_id instead of a string if you use Arel (see my answer below)...

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions

> Only equality, range and subset checking are possible with Hash conditions.

You'll need to either drop down to straight SQL or invert and arel query, see [Is there a way to invert an ActiveRecord::Relation query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302510/is-there-a-way-to-invert-an-arel-query)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're aware, the not equal condition typically does not match (author_id) NULL values. You'll have to do an `OR author_id IS NULL` if you want that.

```
@users = User.where("user_id = ? AND (author_id != ? OR author_id IS NULL)", 
                    current_user.id, current_user.id)

render(@users.present? ? :something : :somethingelse)
```

Also note that I'm using `@users.present?` because `where` finder returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` array.